Extend default formatter functionality
Is it possible to extend default formatter textarea of Tabulator without losing its base functionality?
function myTextarea(cell) {
    var value = cell.getValue().replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
    cell.setValue(value);
    return new Tabulator.formatters.textarea(cell); 
}

